# Get Lowest Elementwise Values from Multiple Numpy Arrays Which May be Different Lengths

Tags: python, numpy

I can get the lowest values from multiple arrays by using the following:

```
first_arr = np.array([0,1,2])
second_arr = np.array([1,0,3])
third_arr = np.array([3,0,4])
fourth_arr = np.array([1,1,9])

print(np.minimum.reduce([first_arr, second_arr, third_arr, fourth_arr]))
```

Result = [0 0 2]

However if the arrays are different lengths or empty I get an error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (4,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

The arrays will often be different lengths or empty. How can I handle this? I want to compare all elements that exist.

So, changing the above example:

```
first_arr = np.array([0,1])
second_arr = np.array([1,0,3])
third_arr = np.array([3,0,4])
fourth_arr = np.array([1,1,9])

print(np.minimum.reduce([first_arr, second_arr, third_arr, fourth_arr]))
```

The result should be [0 0 3].

Comment: can get 400x faster than `zip_longest` and without changing result `dtype`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the overhead, use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)'s [`DataFrame.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html):

```
l = [first_arr, second_arr, third_arr, fourth_arr]

out = pd.DataFrame(l).min().to_numpy()
```

Or with [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) and [`numpy.nanmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

l = [first_arr, second_arr, third_arr, fourth_arr]

out = np.nanmin(np.c_[list(zip_longest(*l, fillvalue=np.nan))], axis=1)
```

Output: `array([0., 0., 3.])`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

lst = [first_arr, second_arr, third_arr, fourth_arr]
out = [min(arr) for arr in zip_longest(*lst, fillvalue=float("inf"))]
print(out)  # or print(np.array(out)) to have output as np.array
```

Prints:

```
[0, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are interested in performance**, the following is faster than `zip_longest`. In my experiments with larger arrays, it can be over 400x faster.

Furthermore, it doesn't change the `dtype` of the result (in the OP's example: `int`):

```py
def min_difflen_np(*arrs):
    out = max(arrs, key=len).copy()
    for a in arrs:
        n = len(a)
        out[:n] = np.minimum(out[:n], a)
    return out

>>> min_difflen_np(first_arr, second_arr, third_arr, fourth_arr)
array([0, 0, 3])
```

#### Speed

We put the `zip_longest` solution in a function:

```py
def min_difflen_zip(*arrs):
    return np.nanmin(np.c_[list(zip_longest(*arrs, fillvalue=np.nan))], axis=1)
```

On the small arrays in the OP's example:

```py
t_np = %timeit -o min_difflen_np(first_arr, second_arr, third_arr, fourth_arr)
# 4.31 µs ± 6.57 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

t_zip = %timeit -o min_difflen_zip(first_arr, second_arr, third_arr, fourth_arr)
# 16.5 µs ± 21.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

>>> t_zip.best / t_np.best
3.8300242340309043
```

Larger sizes:

```py
nmax, m = 10_000, 20
np.random.seed(0)
arrs = [
    np.random.randint(0, 1_000_000, np.random.randint(nmax))
    for _ in range(m)
]

t_np = %timeit -o min_difflen_np(*arrs)
# 79.4 µs ± 50.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

t_zip = %timeit -o min_difflen_zip(*arrs)
# 37.1 ms ± 83.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> t_zip.best / t_np.best
465.7530941482781
```

Comment: Came here to post your solution :)